# What does Kosh mean when he says "I have always been here"?

Tags: babylon-5

"I have always been here" is a famous quote by Kosh, but what does he mean by that?  Does it apply to the other Vorlons or just Kosh?

Comment: He says it a bunch of times in very different circumstances. Sometimes he seems to be referring to his presence in Sheridan's mind (as a 'piece') and other times he seems to be referring to the Vorlon race's presence in the wider galaxy. Hard to say without more context. Also, he's intentionally obtuse.

Comment: Kosh, like many Vorlons are, is really, really old. That might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vorlons, along with a number of other races, are collectively referred to as **the First Ones**. They were among the first races to exist, long before humans. It is established that Kosh himself was over a million years old, as it is revealed he met Lorien, one of the 'First Born', prior to the other early races going over the rim.

Spoiler for the season 2 finale:

> We learn that the Vorlons appeared to many races that came after them, such as the humans and the Mimbari, as their angelic protectors, and became part of their earliest belief systems.

It is in this literal sense that Kosh says "I have always been here". He existed before any of the races he interacts with on Babylon 5, and as 'protector' of the younger races, he is also "there" *for them* in the sense that he is available to help.

Comment: For the record Kosh being over a million years old is established by Lorien meeting him prior to retreating to the pit on Z'ha'dum at the last war between the first ones where most left for beyond the rim.  The last million years being proxy wars or training sessions for the younger races.

Comment: @lucasbachmann That's true, and I'm undecided about which answer to accept/give the bounty to.  For now I'll leave this answer accepted while I decide.

Comment: @Anonymous I already added lucasbachmann's suggestion into my answer. It didn't contradict what I originally wrote, he just cited proof for what I already said.

Comment: @Astralbee lucasbachmann's answer came first...

Comment: @Anonymous No, that's how he was able to quote me. And when you comment on someone's answer, it is supposed to be with the intention of helping improve it - that's the spirit of the site, anyway.

Comment: @Astralbee Which comment are you referring to?  And this answer was on June 18th and yours was on June 21st.

Comment: @Anonymous No, my answer was written on June 18th at 08:06. You're looking at the *edited* date. My original answer said that Kosh was "believed to be" over a million years old. I'm referring to Lucas's comment on my answer that Kosh's age was *established* at that, which I thought was very helpful, and was edited into my answer yesterday. I didn't even know that Lucas had written his own answer. I've looked at it, and it seems to be largely opinion-based, ie "I feel...."

Comment: @Astralbee I assure you your answer in opinion based as well.  It is a fact the timeline is fixed and a fact Vorlons are old.  I believe your answer is true.   But it was incomplete as the Vorlons have much invested in the closed loop timeline they have always been in. Lorien is just trivia I thought folks would find interesting.  Anonymous your acceptance is fine as is of course.   I do enjoy your babylon 5 questions and hope you are getting good answers.

Comment: @lucasbachmann I'm really not fighting over the acceptance or the bounty, but I couldn't allow the suggestion that you answered before me to go uncorrected.

Answer (score 1):

I feel Babylon 5 Fandom had settled on that it is sometimes Kosh making a comment on how the timeline is not being altered from the events of the Valen Sinclair time circle "We have always been here." The response to young Delenn in "In the Beginning".  Also this complements "And so it begins..."

Though certainly it is more nuanced and true in multiple meanings Astralbee's comment that Kosh is a protector of the younger races for a million years is also likely being exclaimed and equally true.   Kosh telling G'kar that after his hallucination seems appropriate and more about the role of Vorlons to the children races rather than a comment on the fixed timeline.

Ultimately the context of each Kosh quote needs to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

We actually do know that Babylon 4 was transported back in time to be used as a Minbari base.  Apparently Vorlons are incredibly long-lived and Kosh may have been present then.  This may have been a statement of literal truth, or more of the cryptic utterances of "normal", Vorlon speach.  There is also some confounding information ofter Kosh's death that his replacement is also "Kosh" and there may be some uncertainty of whether specific individuals or the species as a whole is guiding the destinies of numerous species.   The question might be is "Kosh" a title not a name?